# Javascript if-else statement on nested function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which hides rows, and depending on which button is clicked it will show content depending if it matches the table row

```
$("#example").on("click", function()
{
    var $rowsNo = $("#table tbody tr").hide().filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).text()) === "4"
}).show();
});
```

This works fine. But i want to add an if statement saying if it equals 4 display the content, if it doesn't equal 4, display content for 5. I have tried

```
$("#example").on("click", function()
{

    if ($(this).find("td").eq(0).text()) === "4"){
    var $rowsNo = $("#table tbody tr").hide().filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).text()) === "4"
}).show();
}
else{
    var $rowsNo = $("#table tbody tr").hide().filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).find("td").eq(0).text()) === "5"
}).show();

}
});
```

I get an error of

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===
```

Comment: I have indented your code and found an extra ')'. It should work now

Comment: @AndreiCACIO post your findings as an answer...don't modify his question.

Comment: @AndreiCACIO, if you found a syntax error, don't add it to original post. Either notify the author or write it as an answer if it answers the question

Comment: @smac89 my bad. I will re-edit

Comment: @AndreiCACIO just post an answer don't keep editing his question...

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra ')' in the if statement. This version should work:

```
$("#example").on("click", function() {
  if (
    $(this)
      .find("td")
      .eq(0)
      .text() === "4"
  ) {
    var $rowsNo = $("#table tbody tr")
      .hide()
      .filter(function() {
        return (
          $.trim(
            $(this)
              .find("td")
              .eq(0)
              .text()
          ) === "4"
        );
      })
      .show();
  } else {
    var $rowsNo = $("#table tbody tr")
      .hide()
      .filter(function() {
        return (
          $.trim(
            $(this)
              .find("td")
              .eq(0)
              .text()
          ) === "5"
        );
      })
      .show();
  }
});
```